# Animate conditionally React component with react-spring

Tags: reactjs, animation, react-spring

I have a react component and I want to animate it when the state of the component change.

I am using `useReducer` `const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);`
Then on click I update the `state.isOpen` from false to true or vice versa. In the same component I have this

```
const wrapperStyles = useSpring({
    transform: state.isOpen ? 'translate3d(0, 0, -300px)' : 'translate3d(0, 0, 0)'
  });
```

Finally the component consumes it like this `<StyledWrapper style={wrapperStyles}>`
I expect the transform the be applied and changed when the state changes, but it does not.
I have no idea what I am doing wrong, I am following their simple instructions on the website.

Edit: I tried with `opacity` instead of `transform` and it works fine, so I am doing something wrong with the css transform?

Answer (score 1):

I am answering my own question, so the reason why it wasn't working is that I was using different values.

from `0` to `300px`. It must be the same value so changing to 
`transform: state.isOpen ? 'translate3d(0, 0, -300px)' : 'translate3d(0, 0, **0px)**'`
where 0px makes the difference :)

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

You read this page. 
I search `react-spring`, 
If you use transform, You use `import {useTransition, animated} from 'react-spring'`

not `useSpring()`

https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/use-transition

```js
const [items, set] = useState([...])
const transitions = useTransition(items, item => item.key, {
from: { transform: 'translate3d(0,-40px,0)' },
enter: { transform: 'translate3d(0,0px,0)' },
leave: { transform: 'translate3d(0,-40px,0)' },
})
return transitions.map(({ item, props, key }) =>
<animated.div key={key} style={props}>{item.text}</animated.div>
)
```